# Cassandra Commit Log Sync

Tags: cassandra

```
WARN  [PERIODIC-COMMIT-LOG-SYNCER] 2018-05-16 21:11:14,294 NoSpamLogger.java:94 - Out of 0 commit log syncs over the past 0.00s with average duration of Infinityms, 1 have exceeded the configured commit interval by an average of 74.40ms
WARN  [PERIODIC-COMMIT-LOG-SYNCER] 2018-05-16 21:16:57,844 NoSpamLogger.java:94 - Out of 0 commit log syncs over the past 0.00s with average duration of Infinityms, 1 have exceeded the configured commit interval by an average of 198.69ms
WARN  [PERIODIC-COMMIT-LOG-SYNCER] 2018-05-16 21:24:46,325 NoSpamLogger.java:94 - Out of 0 commit log syncs over the past 0.00s with average duration of Infinityms, 1 have exceeded the configured commit interval by an average of 264.11ms
WARN  [PERIODIC-COMMIT-LOG-SYNCER] 2018-05-16 21:29:46,393 NoSpamLogger.java:94 - Out of 32 commit log syncs over the past 268.84s with, average duration of 17.56ms, 1 have exceeded the configured commit interval by an average of 173.66ms
```

My debug.log is full of these warnings when the cluster is under medium load. Is this something to be worried about? My commit log interval is 10000ms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the period to flush is less than 1.5* the flush period (15000 in your case) this isn't a big deal. Just ignore it.

It displaying the `Infinityms` is a division by zero bug in the stats reporter. Can you open a Jira at https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/CASSANDRA to get it addressed? I don't think thats been reported yet.

Comment: I opened an issue. Thanks for the answer. https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/CASSANDRA/issues/CASSANDRA-14451

Answer (score 2):

There is a fixed issue now https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14451 that maybe affecting the accuracy of those messages (depends on the version)

Jason Brown says:

The bug was using markerIntervalNanos in the wakeUpAt variable as basis for determining if we've lagged in the actual flush to disk. The code should use syncIntervalNanos for that determination. Once again, the only problem here is around determining if we should log about the commitlog flushing falling behind, not that the commitlog is actually falling behind (it ins't, at least as far as the overlogging here is concerned). Most of the change was moving the logging code out of the primary AbstractCommitLogService.SyncRunnable#sync() and into a subroutine. This allowed me to add unit tests, as well as clean up/clarify the sync() method.
It was according to Jason introduced in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14108

So if you're in the affected version the calculation is unfortunately incorrect (and there is a number of perf regressions in other versions).